# Select columns by their values

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'Consumer Staples': [-0.065], 'Technology': [0.04], 'Financials': [0.06], 'Health Care': [0.07]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I only want to return the names of the columns whose absolute value of  `Value` is greater than 0.05. In this example, it should return Consumer Staples, Financials, And Health Care, but not Technology. How do I do this on Pandas?

Thank you!

Comment: didn't downvote but you need to include your code as text, raw data to recreate your df, your attempts and the desired result. Not a link to an image

Comment: @EdChum Hi EdChum, I just wrote the code as text.

Comment: `df.columns[df.gt(0.05).values[0]]` or are you after absolute value? in which case `df.columns[df.abs().gt(0.05).values[0]]`

Comment: @EdChum Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future include your code as text, your raw data, the code to reproduce your df and the desired result.

You can achieve this using [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html) to return the absolute value, and [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt) for greater than to generate a boolean mask, we can use this to mask the columns. Note that here because we have a dataframe, the mask is a dataframe also, to get just the boolean values use `.values` to return a numpy array, this is a nested list so you need to index using the subscript operator `[]`:

```
In[112]:
df.columns[df.abs().gt(0.05).values[0]]

Out[112]: Index(['Consumer Staples', 'Financials', 'Health Care'], dtype='object')
```

If you want a list of string, call `tolist()`:

```
In[116]:
df.columns[df.abs().gt(0.05).values[0]].tolist()

Out[116]: ['Consumer Staples', 'Financials', 'Health Care']
```

Comment: thank you so much. Next time, I will do a better job.

Comment: Just one last question, how would I print out the names of the columns individually  as strings instead of the whole columns as `Index` type?